# How to prove that this set $T = \{(i,j,k,z) \mid i,j,k,z ∈ \mathbb N\}$ is countable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$T = \{(i,j,k,z) \mid i,j,k,z ∈ \mathbb N\}$

How to prove that this set is countable? I understand how to do it with triples by finding one-to-one function from $T$ to $\mathbb N$, but I cannot understand how to use this approach in case of quadruples.

Comment: Can you do it for doubles and then for doubles again?

Answer (score 3):

An easy 1-1 function $\mathbb N^4 \to \mathbb N$:
$$
\alpha(i,j,k,z) = 2^i 3^j 5^k 7^z
$$
For more than $4$ arguments, use more primes: $11, 13, 17, \dots$.